# Using jQuery, how to modify text outside of tags?

Tags: jquery, html, string

Given a string of text that is both adjacent to a span and inside of a div, what are some methods to modify just that text, leaving the surrounding HTML intact?  For example:

```
<div id="my-div">modify this text<span id="my-span"></span></div>
```

I have tried things like

```
$('#my-div').html(function(i, elem){blah;});
```

but this seems to cause the span to be deleted and a new span to be added (I notice that some styling is lost on the span).

I realize that it would be best to wrap the text string in its own HTML tags before applying client-side code, but that is out of my control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$('#my-div').contents()
            .filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; })
            .replaceWith('new text or html');
```

nodeType == 3 is to test for a text node.

Comment: I was going to write this very thing as the correct solution when I saw yours pop up here.  Nice!

Answer (score 2):

What about using jQuery's `contents()` method?

http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var elems = $('#myDiv *').detach();

  $('#myDiv').text('new texts...').append(elems);

})​
```

quick [demo](http://jsbin.com/osaqa)

**edit**

or as alex suggested to use `.contents()`:

```
  $('#myDiv').contents()
    .filter(function(){
       return this.nodeType != 1 && $.trim($(this).text()) != '';        
    })
    .replaceWith("I am the new text");
```

Comment: Again, this destroys the spans and replaces them with new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying its HTML string, modify its DOM tree, find the top-level text nodes and do with them.

Comment: This makes sense, but how do I isolate the text as some kind of object?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use string replace:

HTML

```
<div id="my-div">modify this text <span id="my-span">or this text here</span></div>
```

Script

```
$('#my-div').html(function(i,html){
 return html.replace('this text', 'some new text').replace('or this text', 'and replace this text');
})
```

Comment: This does the same thing I mentioned before.  It replaces text, destroying DOM objects.

Comment: How does it destroy DOM objects when it's replacing text? Now if I added `.replace('<span id="my-span">','')` sure that will destroy the span, but you are intentionally doing it in this case.