# Remove a specific text after div

Tags: jquery

Im trying to delete the text (Costa Rica, United States) after the #box01 and #box02 divs.

```
<div id="box01">

  Costa Rica

  <div>100 percent</div>

<div>

<div id="box02">

  United States

  <div>99 ballons</div>

<div>
```

To produce:

```
<div id="box01">

  <div>100 percent</div>

<div>

<div id="box02">

  <div>99 ballons</div>

<div>
```

My problem is that Costa Rica and United States are not inside a `<p>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: then put them inside a `<p>` tag.

Comment: Is there ever other text that is directly a child of your boxes that you want to preserve?

Comment: I asked a very similar question and got a really great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742223/using-jquery-how-to-modify-text-outside-of-tags

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to put those results inside a p tag, because are part of a core API not managed by me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this(uses contents, filter & replaceWith):

```
$(function () {
    $("#box01, #box02").contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType != 1;
    }).replaceWith("");
});
```

Sample @ jsFiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/CwTa8/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any answer, so I'll give you what I can come up with even if it's not pretty.  You can get the div contents with `$('div#box01').html()`.  You can alter that string using something like regex replace() and then call `$('div#box01').replaceWith(newContentYouJustMade)`.

It's not pretty, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the div to be in the child then this would work without using a regex since the content is already there.  You could loop over a list of the ids.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box01').replaceWith($('#box01').children());
    $('#box02').replaceWith($('#box02').children());
});
```

Comment: That will remove the boxes themselves, which is likely undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#box01, #box02').html( function(i,oldHTML){
  return oldHTML.replace(/^[^<]+/,'');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify Cybernate's solution to make it for all div containing 'box' inside ID

```
$(function () {
    $("div[id*=box]").contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType != 1;
    }).replaceWith("");
});
```